# Django python: 'init_command' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bookingsystem'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It returns the error:

```
TypeError: 'init_command' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I'm looking to create new tables on my database, but when I reload phpmyadmin through XAMPP nothing changes. I can't seem to figure out the error, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I was trying to follow the guide:
https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-database/

Comment: But this is clearly not looking at your MySQL installation, it's looking at a local sqlite file.

Comment: The guide is using MySQL but you are using SQLite, what do you really want to use?

Comment: `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` is not the correct engine for MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'`to `ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'`